# Why do we need diffusion currents to explain semiconductor current flow?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, diffusion

Why do we need the idea of carrier concentrations to explain current flow? Can we simply not associate the disparity in carrier concentrations between two samples to a disparity in relative charge thus leading to a formation of an electric field that causes a drift current?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reasoning here; differently doped materials have different carrier concentrations but are nonetheless charge neutral.  Please expand on your reasoning.

Comment: I see. I overlooked charge neutrality. I understand.

Comment: What's more, you acn add an external electric field, which adds a drif although there's equality of concentrations.

Answer (score 1):

Diffusion currents play a significant role in the operation of semiconductors.  Circuit analysis would give incorrect results if they were ignored.  The reverse-bias current in a diode is diffusion current; ignoring it means getting the wrong answer in detailed analysis.  The electron current from emitter to base in an active npn transistor is also diffusion current, and is an essential ingredient to its operation.  Ignoring it here leads to the conclusion that transistors don't work!

Comment: My question does not imply we ignore them, instead can we not explain them in terms of charge disparity rather than concentration gradients?

Comment: Sorry.  But I still don't understand the question.  Are you suggesting that a concentration gradient causes an electric field which in turn drives the carriers?  If so, then no, you can't.  Diffusion currents run in both directions.  In a reverse bias pn junction, the diffusion current runs the "wrong" way ... electrons move toward the higher concentration of electrons.

Comment: Yes that is my question. But im not quite sure why you say electrons diffuse the wrong way under reverse bias? As far as i know, Diffusion happens in the "correct" way albeit it is inhibited by the potential barrier.

Comment: garyp, if I'm not mistaken, diffusion current goes to zero under reverse bias conditions leaving just the drift current component for the reverse current.

Comment: Nope - other way around. Drift is from fields, diffusion is non-directional.

Comment: For reference:  *"Under reverse bias, both diffusion components are negligible because of the large barrier at the junction, and the only current is the relatively small (and essentially voltage dependent) generation current from n to p"*  (from "Reference Data for Engineers")

Comment: "negligible" depends on the application.  For transistor operation, it is not negligible.

Comment: Better comment:  what is meant by "generation current" in that quote?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of drift and diffusion currents comes up when discussing the semi-classical model of the charge carrier flow in a semiconductor. In the model, the charge carriers (electrons and holes) are 'relatively free' to move about in random motion in the lattice formed by the semiconductor. However, they are scattered by the various atoms of the semiconductor and donor/acceptor ions in a lattice.

Speaking of the disparity of charge, the various regions of the semiconductor are always neutral during normal operation. However, since the behavior of the holes and electrons can be described as classical particles, with reduced masses (and hence the label semi-classical), they also follow motion similar to classical particles, like atoms of a gas, etc., and hence, diffusion currents should be expected.

It must be understood that diffusion currents are not due to the lattice 'pushing around' the electrons and holes because of the difference in concentration; it is purely a result of the random motion of the particles. If the concentration of the particles varies across the crystal, you would expect that, due to the random motion, they spread around evenly (although potential may be generated, causing drift of the charge carriers; but that is not what we are talking about).

Comment: Careful how you word this.  Non-equilibrium concentration differences lead to a net diffusion current.

Answer (score 0):

I like this question! I happen to have the same argument in my head. You see, this diffusion current is purely a diffusion thing. Just like the gas particles diffuse across the permeable membrane. From the higher to lower concentration. There is no charge disparity involved as semiconductors are charge neutral as whole. Yes, they are charge neutral even when differentially doped.

But if one side has more electrons than the other? There have respective ions there too! It is charge neutral everywhere.
Any electric field has to be external unless... diffusion!
Now the things which are mobile (the carriers that is) will creep into spacious territories. But can they? No, the ions will not let them go and generate ad hoc electric fields to make them stay.

A "sticky" equilibrium is reached.

> I like to think of it as when I threw the Pizza to the ceiling and the cheese got stuck and didn't let
> it fall!